# How would I replace the second instance of a character in the URL?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to replace the second instance only of of the '&' character or replace all instances of '&' after the first '&' in the URL www.website.com/--Inventory&vt=test%20&%20unit

so far I've been using:

```
var url = window.location.toString();
window.location = url.replace(/&/, '%26');
window.location.reload(false);
```

but that replaces all the '&' characters. any ideas are appreciated. thanks!

Comment: you want to keep the first one and replace only the second and let anything there after stay the same as '&'  like the first instance or do you only want the first instance to remain an '&' and everything else '%26'

Comment: @ToreanJoel yeah I think having the first instance to remain an '&' and everything else '%26' is more of what I was asking

Comment: The provided url does not look valid to me I always thought that it should have a ? before any &'s for example: www.website.com/--Inventory?vt=tes&vt=unit or  www.website.com/--Inventory?vt=tes%26unit

Comment: You almost certainly want to do this with the `encodeURIComponent` method, not hand massage special characters in URLs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select the position of the 2nd `&` character in your url by passing the (index of first `&` character) + 1 as 2nd parameter to indexOf function.

2nd argument of the `indexOf`  function defines the index of the string from which character should be searched from.

learn more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf)

(In this case, the search starts from the 1 + index of first `&` character)

```
var position = url.indexOf("&", url.indexOf("&") + 1);
```

Now you can replace the character at the `position` as follows:

```
url=url.substr(0, position) + '%26' + url.substr(position + 1);
```

```js
var url = "www.website.com/--Inventory&vt=test%20&%20unit";

var position = url.indexOf("&", url.indexOf("&") + 1);

url=url.substr(0, position) + '%26' + url.substr(position + 1);

console.log(url)
```

Answer (score 0):

Dirty, but works...

```
var url = window.location.toString();
var explode = url.split("&");
url = "";
for(int i=0; i<explode.length; i++) {
    url+=exlode[i];
    if(i!=explode.length-1) {
        if(i==1){
            url+="%26";
        } else {
            url+="&";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's what my boss says about me every now and then

Answer (score 0):

```js
String.prototype.replaceAt=function(index, character) {
    return this.substr(0, index) + character + this.substr(index+1, this.length);
}

var url="www.website.com/--Inventory&vt=test%20&%20unit";
url=url.split("").reverse().join("");
var index=url.indexOf("&");
url=url.replaceAt(index,"62%");
url=url.split("").reverse().join("");
console.log(url);
```

and result is:

**www.website.com/--Inventory&vt=test%20%26%20unit**